# Disable OK button when FolderBrowserDialog SelectedPath is MyComputer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

In my program, I need to force the user to select the save folder. I'm doing this by setting the SelectedPath to be MyComputer.

My problem is the OK button is not initially disabled.

Behaviour:

- "My Computer" is selected (light shade of grey) but the OK button is enabled.
- Clicking on "My Computer" (selection now shaded dark blue) still has the OK button selected.
- If I select say Desktop and then re-select "My Computer", the OK button only then gets disabled.

I've tried playing around with both the SelectedPath and RootFolder, along with Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer and Environment.GetPath() to no avail.

How can I disable the OK button when the SelectedPath is not a valid folder?

**EDIT:**
This is running on Windows XP, .Net 4.0, developed in Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

**EDIT #2:** Full example code added.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FolderBrowser
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
            this.button1.Text = "Open FolderBrowserDialog";
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SelectSaveFolderItem_Click);

            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SelectSaveFolderItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            fbd.SelectedPath = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
            fbd.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I run this on my machine and get your expected behaviour. Win 7 / .NET 4.0. Is this the complete code for initialising your FBD?

Comment: Just as an aside: This is a terrible way to design a UI. You should be offering a suggested location for them to save, rather than initially displaying an invalid location with a disabled button to indicate that fact. You can get a suggested location with `Environment.SpecialFolder` easily.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winforms/thread/48bf0547-1e1d-446f-8d18-c395491d0d60

Comment: @KenWhite Fair point & understand the comment. The rationale is the data to be saved has security implications & while we don't want to completely lock out saving to the laptop harddrive, the preferred save loaction is removable media.

Comment: Why not try and point to removable media instead if you can, rather than just `My Computer`? Especially since it's so easy to determine in .NET with `Environment.GetLogicalDrives()`, and `DriveInfo.DriveType()`.

Comment: Implemented solution combines Ken's and Jeremy's feedback. If removable media are present, it selects the first one as a default. Otherwise, it selects My Computer, and uses the timer event to disable the button on the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref: [MSDN: Disable a button in a folder browser dialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winforms/thread/48bf0547-1e1d-446f-8d18-c395491d0d60)

In the above msdn thread a user wished to disable the accept button in folder browser dialog when a directory didn't exist. I feel this relates to your question:
`How can I disable the OK button when the SelectedPath is not a valid folder?`

The solution in that thread is to use a Timer event to disable the OK Button after the dialog is shown. I converted the VB.Net code to C# for you:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Form1
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

    private static extern Int32 FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowExA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

    private static extern Int32 FindWindowEx(Int32 hWnd1, Int32 hWnd2, string lpsz1, string lpsz2);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

    private static extern Int32 EnableWindow(Int32 hwnd, Int32 fEnable);


    private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled = true;

        FolderBrowserDialog fld = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        fld.ShowDialog(this);

    }


    private void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 hwndMainWindow = default(Int32);

        hwndMainWindow = FindWindow("#32770".Trim(), Constants.vbNullString);
        // '#32770 (Dialog)#32770 (Dialog)


        if (hwndMainWindow) {
            Int32 hwndBtn = default(Int32);

            hwndBtn = FindWindowEx(hwndMainWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "OK");


            if (hwndBtn) {
                EnableWindow(hwndBtn, 0);

            }

        }

        Timer1.Enabled = false;

    }

}
```